# Fourier transform in MATLAB misunderstood peaks

Tags: matlab, fourier-transform

I have a function:

```
t1 = 0:1/50:4-1/50;
x1 = cos(pi*t1);

t2 = 4:1/50:8-1/50;
x2 = cos(3*pi*t2);

t3 = 8:1/50:12-1/50;
x3 = cos(2*pi*t3);
```

Which is written in MATLAB. I create a signal which appends of  x1, x2 and x3 - signals appears consequently one after another and each of them lasts for 4 seconds.

When I perform Fourier transform i receive magnitude-frequency plot with characteristic peaks at: 1Hz, 2Hz, 3Hz and also 47Hz, 48Hz, 49Hz. As in the picture:

[Signal 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOhFN.png)

Can you please explain me the origin of 47, 48 and 49 Hz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I solved this problem.
It's simply because of Nyquist theorem. Sampling rate of given signal is 50Hz, so the max. frequency that can be represented on a graph is 25Hz.
Those peaks at 47,48,49 Hz are a concequence of imaginary part of coeficients that are calculated by Fourier transform.

I hope this will help someone in the future.